# Accessing app.config in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, app-config, appsettings

I am using app.config file to read data from it..
I am loading the app.config file as:

```
string app_path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("app.config");
xmlDoc.Load(app_path);

string image_path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test1"];
```

and i want to get the value of "Test1". But the value of test1 is comming "null"..
how can i get the value of "test1" from app.config file..
i created the app.config file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Test1" value="My value 1" />
    <add key="Test2" value="Another value 2" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

please help me out..

Comment: There is no `app.config` in asp.net, you need to use `web.config` instead.

Comment: If you're running ASP.NET you need to use Web.config, not App.config

Comment: Anyway, don't load web.config/app.config as XmlDocument. Use built-in infrastructure members instead.

Comment: how can this be done????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ASP.NET applications, the default configuration file is named web.config. This is a convention you should probably stick to, that allows you to easily use the `ConfigurationManager` to access configuration settings.

I suggest having a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config as a starting point to learn the ins and outs of basic .NET application configuration in the ASP.NET domain.

You can link configuration files together, by setting the `file` attribute of configuration sections you want to override: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/appsettings_fileattribute.aspx

Comment: if i had to use some personel setting then i have to give it in web.config file, inside "<appsettings>".

Answer (score 10):

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Test1" value="My value 1" />
    <add key="Test2" value="Another value 2" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
string image_path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test1"];
```

Comment: Yes, but in an ASP.NET application, you have to use the web.config file, not the app.config file.

Comment: yes i have used web.config  and rename it to app.config file. is this possible....

Comment: No. It needs to be named WEB.CONFIG. The .net configuration environment uses a set of conventions where files need to be named certain things for the ConfigurationManager to work.

Comment: but i get from certain website that app.config is used to do some personel settings in .config file

Comment: @percy: In ASP.NET, default config is called Web.config, any other - is custom and optional. So you can name it App.config (like in WinForms) or anyhow else, Foo.config or Config\Bar.config. Custom loader (`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()`) is required to load and read such file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings inside a web application, you have to put your AppSettings section in web.config.