# How properly configure authentication for consuming external Restful Apis in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm consuming an external Restful Api. I supplied the authorization key for the headers value. When I try to send a request with postman it return 200 Ok I use the API KEY same on the code. What is proper way to consume a Restful Api with Authorization Key?

I already configure the Startup.cs for ConfigureServices and Configure. Then I use the HttpClient for consuming the Restful Api. Somehow I get an 401 Unauthorized response.

Code for Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });

    services.AddAuthentication();
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{       
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Code for Services.cs:

```
private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

public CRUDService()
{
    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.deezer.com");

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-API_KEY", "081f0fca-1bca-4e8e-9a24-22ff2c3d462c");

    _httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}

public async Task Run()
{
    await GetResource();
}

public async Task GetResource()
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/v1/song/latest");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var movies = new List<Movie>();

    if (response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json")
    {
        movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really hope thats not your actual API key...

Comment: @MattOestreich yeah, that right. For security purpose. I'm sorry. Do you have an idea how globally register that API Key in Startup.cs so it can access through out the application? Thanks

Comment: You would use an app.config/web.config file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989736/accessing-app-config-in-asp-net

Comment: ASP.NET Core has a whole [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) system for *where* to store things like API Keys. An [environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider) might be a good place for production workflows (or [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2) if you're in Azure).

Comment: I recommend reading through [Initiate HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to get a good idea of how to use `HttpClient` effectively.

Comment: @KirkLarkin yeah, I'm getting this exception why is that? 'This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.'

Comment: Share us what your postman request is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a 600 invalid query on that api, so I can't confirm.  But, I think you need to add the api key like this:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API_KEY", "081f0fca-1bca-4e8e-9a24-22ff2c3d462c");
```

...instead of adding it to DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work, but it doesn't look like you are instantiating/initializing the CRUDService - you may need to do something like this:

```
public async Task GetResource()
{
    CRUDService(); // <<<<---- this was added <<<<----
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/v1/song/latest");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var movies = new List<Movie>();

    if (response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json")
    {
        movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(content);
    }
}
```